# Ejercicio logica en JavaScript - seis amigos

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, javascript-objeto

En mi conquista por aprender bien JavaScript intento realizar ejercicios de logica, buscando que junto a js pueda dar soluciones.

he estado estudiando lo relacionado al Frontend y quiero desarrollar la mejor manera para utilizar JavaScript de manera mas eficiente.
Tengo el siguiente ejercicio, pero no ***consigo valores especificos*** ademas que **me gustaria mostrar la propiedad y no el valor del objeto**. Podrian ayudarme a esta solucion para visualizarlo en consola?

```
var v = {

    Alejandro: {
        coche: 1,
        avion: 2,
        tren: 3
    },
    Benito: {
        coche: 1,
        avion: 2,
        tren: 3
    },
    Andres: {
        coche: 1,
        avion: 2,
        tren: 3
    },
    Carlos: {
        coche: 1,
        avion: 2,
        tren: 3
    },
    Dario: {
        coche: 1,
        avion: 2,
        tren: 3
    },
    Tomas: {
        coche: 1,
        avion: 2,
        tren: 3
    },
    resultado: function () {

        if (!v.Alejandro.coche || !v.Alejandro.avion &&
            !v.Benito.coche || !v.Benito.avion &&
            !v.Andres.coche || !v.Andres.tren &&
            !v.Carlos.avion || !v.Carlos.tren &&
            !v.Dario.coche || v.Dario.tren &&
            !v.Tomas.avion || v.Tomas.tren) {

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }, 

    intervalo: setInterval(function(){

        v.Alejandro = Math.ceil(Math.random()*3);
        v.Benito = Math.ceil(Math.random()*3);
        v.Andres = Math.ceil(Math.random()*3);
        v.Carlos = Math.ceil(Math.random()*3);
        v.Dario = Math.ceil(Math.random()*3);
        v.Tomas = Math.ceil(Math.random()*3);

        if (v.resultado()){

            clearInterval(v.intervalo);
            console.log('Alejandro va en ', v.Alejandro);
            console.log('Benito va en ', v.Benito);
            console.log('Andres va en ', v.Andres);
            console.log('Carlos va en ', v.Carlos);
            console.log('Dario va en ', v.Dario);
            console.log('Tomas va en ', v.Tomas);
        }
    }, 1)

}
```

Y el resultado a mostrar seria:

Caso #4  AMIGOS DE VACACIONES
Seis amigos desean pasar sus vacaciones juntos y deciden, cada dos, utilizar diferentes medios de transporte; sabemos que Alejandro no utiliza el coche ya que éste acompaña a Benito que no va en avión. Andrés viaja en avión. Si Carlos no va acompañado de Darío ni hace uso del avión, podría Vd. decirnos en qué medio de transporte llega a su destino Tomás.

1.Alejandro
2.Benito
3.Andres
4.Carlos
5.Dario
6.Tomas

Por lo tanto:
Alejandro y Benito -> Tren

Andres y Dario -> Avion

Carlos y Tomas -> Auto (Coche)

Comment: Lo que esstás haciendo no es _nada_ eficiente... cada uno de ellos debería ser una sola estructura común.... piensa en un object `Persona` y una propiedad sería el nombre, aparte de las otras que ya defines.... podrías guardar los 6 objetos en un arreglo y entonces puedes hacer recorridos a traves de ellos, en vez de colocar 6 ifs para hacer una verificación.

Comment: Mas o menos entiendo, podrias ayudarme en la construccion ? hace poco empece con ejercicios para mejorar la solucion de problemas, pero aun no he pulido la formacion de las funciones.

Comment: Te recomiendo leer [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), no queda claro cuál es la pregunta y/o problema en específico.

Answer (score 0):

```
const persona = [
{
 name: 'Alejandro',
 vehiculos: ['Tren'],
},
{
 name: 'Benito',
 vehiculos: ['Tren'],
}, 
{
  name: 'Andres',
  vehiculos: ['Avion'],
},
{
  name: 'Carlos',
  vehiculos: ['Coche'],
},
{
  name: 'Dario',
  vehiculos: ['Avion'],
},
{
  name: 'Tomas',
  vehiculos: [],
},  
];

for (index in persona){
   if(persona[index].vehiculos == 'Tren') {
      console.log(persona[index]);    
    } else if(persona[index].vehiculos == 'Avion') {
      console.log(persona[index])
    } else if(persona[index].vehiculos == 'Coche') {
      console.log(persona[index])
    } else {
      persona[index].vehiculos.push('Coche');
      console.log(persona[index]);
    }
```

};